\verb like macro passing argument to a standalone Lua code
I would like to process content verbatim in a standalone Lua file. The solution from this post does not work in my "delocalized" Lua code. Why? Is there a fix?
\documentclass{article}

\directlua{
function readverb(txt)
     print()
     print("=== VERBATIM - START")
     print(txt)
     print("=== VERBATIM - END")
     print()
end
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\passToLua}{v}{
    \directlua{readverb(#1)}
}

\begin{document}

\passToLua{a string with # \ and %}

\end{document}


I'm not a lua expert, but it works with \directlua{readverb([[#1]])}. The double brackets are taken from the linked solution.

Because we work a literal string, we also need to use Lua string delimiters, but to avoid unwanted side effects, we must use literal string delimiters. Shame on me! ;-) Thank you @jlab for pointing that.
\documentclass{article}

\directlua{
function readverb(txt)
     print()
     print("=== VERBATIM - START")
     print(txt)
     print("=== VERBATIM - END")
     print()
end
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\passToLua}{v}{
    \directlua{readverb([[#1]])}
}

\begin{document}

\passToLua{a string with # \ and %}

\end{document}

